# custom Icon commandButton using CSS

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I can't get a custom icon to my commandButton as explained in lots of other questions.

Folderstructure:

- web/resources/icons/plus.png
- web/resources/css/style.css

style.css:

```
.ui-icon-myAdd{
    background-image: url("#{resource['icons/plus.png']}") !important;
}
```

header:

```
<h:head>
    ...
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css"/>
</h:head>
```

button:

```
<p:commandButton value="..." icon="ui-icon-myAdd"/>
```

If I use styleClass instead of icon, my button's background is set to the image I'm trying to use as icon (which should be correct). So i guess there is no problem with the pathing.
Still the icon of my button is empty using the icon-tag.

Where am I wrong? What am I missing?
I've tried everything I found so far. Might be something pretty basic as I just started with JSF and primefaces.

I use:

- PrimeFaces-5.2
- Mojaara-2.2.1
- IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2
- Tomcat 9.0.0.M8

Comment: Did you look at the client-side html? Look what **is** applied?

Comment: thats generated for the empty space of the button: <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-myAdd"></span>

and the css class is applied yes (just as the png is visible)

Comment: looks good to me, your class is applied... Is the css also 'active'? (learn how to use browser developer tools) Are you sure the image is not e.g. to big? To much whitespace around it? This question as it is now is not JSF or PF related, but purely a css thing.

Comment: i couldn't find any specs on the size of icons, its 128x128, but i've tried a smaller one too

Comment: oh well, seems like the smaller one i've tried was even too big. 16x16 works fine now... thx a lot for that hint

Comment: And this can all be easily found out by using browser developer tools... Next time, please use them.